# How to calculate dynamic size on scrollview for iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have dynamic no of textviews and their size can also be dynamic, after each text view there are also dynamic no of labels, and each item is place on scroll view, so that scroll view also has dynamic size, So Someone guide me how to accomplish this task?
forgive me if this is repetitive question plz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting dynamic height of UILabel or UITextView, you can implement following method

This example is for UILabel, Remember, you need to set noOfLines property before setting dynamic height, you can set noOfLines to max number.

```
NSString *text = @"Your text here";
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:lblName.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(lblName.frame.size.width, 10000)];

scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, size.height);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What you need,

1 calculate textsize which you are going to to show on differnt controls.
for this use this line 
 `[titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(285,9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`

2 Also use labels instead of textView at each place if you only need to show text.
because textViews justify the text means your same line can be fit in one line but also in two lines

3 set the scrollView contentSize as above answers says.by adding all textSizes with consider some spaces between various controls.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the size of scrollview using `setContentSize:` and query size `[scrollView contentSize]`